# Recipes for managing contacts who leave companies (Drupal)?

Tags: contacts, drupal-7

Can anyone point me to best practice or recipes for dealing with staff contacts when they leave a company that is running CiviCRM, especially when the person may have created content in both Drupal and in Civi?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest approach would be to block the Drupal account, no other action is required.

If you must delete the Drupal account for a given reason, make sure you select ‘Delete the account and make its content belong to the anonymous user’, otherwise the content created by this user will also be deleted.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Anil - how do you deal with the contact in CiviCRM?

Comment: I would just leave the record as is in order to preserve that person's history in the organization. Maybe create a tag or group to identify those people.